# php Header: location will not go without a break but break causes error?

Tags: php

I have a page that if it's linked to directly redirects to the home page

```
if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])){
    header("Location: http://www.MYWEBSITE.com");
    break;
}
```

without the break I get a white page as it continues to run but with the break causes `PHP Fatal error:  Cannot break/continue 1 level`. I get that making it an `if }else { statement` resolves it - I just think it's messy but I would like to know why the first header statement isn't acted up on at the time and if there's a better way of doing it.

Comment: break is for terminating loops. You don't have one, so you can't use break.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace `break;` with `exit;` instead.

The `break` doesn't work that way , you are not inside any nested loops and that is why you get that `FATAL` error.

#### The right way...

```
if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])){
    header("Location: http://www.MYWEBSITE.com");
    exit;
}
```

Comment: It's strange but I'm sure I'd used exit before and had changed it for break as exit wasn't working correctly - thanks - it's working perfectly now.